# Custom endpoint in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to write the custom endpoint for Spring Boot applications. I have written the custom Endpoint implementation as below. I have not included the extra things like import for reduce the size of code.

```
@Component
public class TestendPoint implements Endpoint<List<String>>{

    public String getId() {
        return "test";      
    }

    public List<String> invoke() {
        List<String> test= new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add("Details 1");
        test.add("Details 2");
        return serverDetails;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {        
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isSensitive() {      
        return false;
    }

}
```

Once I have written the above code, I have restarted the application and tring to access endpoint from /test. But, the endpoint is not available. The following is the Spring Boot start application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application{

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Apart from that, I have everything to run a Spring Boot Actuator. I could access the default endpoints like /info,/metrics, etc.

Could you share your knowledge if I am missing anything here. I am assuming that the custom endpoint class will be loaded without ant further configurations from developer.

Comment: Should I include @ComponentScan in the spring boot application class. If I add then I am getting exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. First, I have not included the @ComponentScan annotation in the application class. Or either I should have @SpringBoot Application. When I added the annotation, I have started getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition owing to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isConditionMatch(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:361)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:345)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:278)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.anyMatches(SpringBootCondition.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$DatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:44)
    ... 24 more
```

This is due to the package. I have tried executing main class from the root package. I am not sure if this is an bug in spring boot application, I would log a JIRA in their site. Once I have added one more level of package structure, it started working fine.

Comment: No, it's not a bug. When you put your spring boot app in the root package  you have a fat warn log that is supposed to let you know something will probably break. See [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-the-default-package)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: But I have not used default package to get that exception. I used root package for component scan

Comment: Your problem looks exactly [like this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1839)

Comment: I have created new issue #3850